# Series $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{5}{4^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{5}{4^n}$$

I tried writing out the values for n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 so try to find partial sum equation but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I've edited your post to include MathJax. Please verify that it's correct.

Comment: It is correct, thank you. I use to be able to use LaTex but forgot. So thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 10):

HINT: First pull out the factor of $5$ and simplify what’s left:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac5{4^n}=5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{4^n}=5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}4\right)^n\;.$$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^n$ is a geometric series; do you know a formula for the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: Yes ahhh makes sense now a/(1-r).

Comment: @user71181: That’s right. (And here you even get $a=1$, if you’ve factored out the $5$.)

Comment: The above formula a/(1-r) only works when n starts at 1. I did the conversion by replacing n with n - 1. I got r to be -1/4, a = 1 and the answer to be 4. Is this correct?

Comment: @user71181: The formula works for any starting value of $n$, provided that $a$ is the first term. Yes, the final result is $$5\cdot\frac1{1-\left(-\frac14\right)}=5\cdot\frac45=4\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Your sum is related to the geometric series

> $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^n=\frac{1}{1+x},\quad |x|<1. $$

**Added:**

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{5}{4^n}=5 \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)^n = 5\frac{1}{1+(1/4)}=4.$$